# Extracting Cakephp Multidimensional arrays

Tags: cakephp

I need to find all the records from an array of id ( `$user_id = array();` ) to be saved into a table of notifications, to tell these users that their accounts are activated.

After executed these,

```
$x = $this->User->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('User.id'=>$user_id)));
$find = Set::extract('/User', $x);
```

I get this result:

```
Array( 
       [0] => Array
       (
              [User] => Array
              (
                [id] => 2
                [name] => joe
                [age] => 13
                [class] => D
              )

       )
       [1] => Array
       (
               [User] => Array
               (
                [id] => 3
                [name] => lambert
                [age] => 14
                [class] => E
              )

       )
    )
```

I need to achive the array below by extracting the one above

```
Array
{
   [id] => 2
   [name] => joe
   [age] => 13
   [class] => D
}
Array
{
   [id] => 3
   [name] => lambert
   [age] => 14
   [class] => E
}
```

How to make this happen using CakePHP?
Then, inside my view, how to send multiple records based on the extracted array above?
Is it possible to make a foreach loop inside view?

```
 echo $html->link(__('Send',true),array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'notifications',$user_id),array('class'=>'button'));
```

Obviously, putting the link inside the loop will result in two links with different ids ($user_id = 2 and $user_id = 3). I don't want that to happen. I want a single link that will submit these ids in one go.

Comment: 1) Yes you could loop in view. 2) Doesn't a form make more sense, then you could use a button to POST all the ids. Although, extracting all the ids like `{n}.User.id` and passing that to `link()` method  should work. Creating a url that looks like `controller/action/id[]=1&id[]=2` afaik. Still a POST makes more sense.

Comment: To be more clear about the latter part of my comment, `'id' => $arrOfExtractedIds` in the link array (2nd param of `link()` method. Or $ids = array('id' => $arrOfExtractedIds'); and `'?' => $ids` to pass as GET params

Comment: In the view, I didn't create forms. Form is created inside the controller (including saveAll). I do `$this->set('users_details',$users_details)` to display all the users information inside the .ctp file.(Just for display - name,class etc.). The Submit button is the only thing that will run the submission. Can this be achived without `$this->User->create` inside the view? Simply said, the users info is already saved inside the controller, I just need to notify them that their accounts are ready by clicking the Submit button that will send out the information to them.

Comment: I suggest you use bin.cakephp.org and paste your controller, model, and form as I can't understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for your first question

```
 $data_final =array();
    foreach($findas $d)
    {
        $data_final[]  =$d['User'];
    }
```

then you wil achive

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => joe
            [age] => 13
            [class] => D
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => lamber
            [age] => 23
            [class] => E
        )

)
```

The answer to second question
the way you are doing with url is not a good practice. you should post the records

Comment: There are two typos in the foreach loop.

Comment: what do u mean by two typos ?

Comment: `foreach($$findas $d)` Should be `foreach($find as $d)`